# Ordering a dataframe by each column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   ID  Age  Score
0   9    5      3
1   4    6      1
2   9    7      2
3   3    2      1
4  12    1     15
5   2   25      6
6   9    5      4
7   9    5     61
8   4    2     12
```

I want to sort based on the first column, then the second column, and so on.

So I want my output to be this:

```
   ID  Age  Score
5   2   25      6
3   3    2      1
8   4    2     12
1   4    6      1
0   9    5      3
6   9    5      4
7   9    5     61
2   9    7      2
4  12    1     15
```

I know I can do the above with `df.sort_values(df.columns.to_list())`, however I'm worried this might be quite slow for much larger dataframes (in terms of columns and rows).

Is there a more optimal solution?

Comment: In order to provide the optimal solution, one would need to have access to the dataframes, as that might change depending on the content of the df. Another alternative could be `columns = ['ID', 'Age', 'Score']
df = df.sort_values(by=columns)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) to improve performance.

```
import numpy as np

a = df.to_numpy()
out = pd.DataFrame(a[np.lexsort(np.rot90(a))],
                   index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Assuming as input a random square DataFrame of side `n`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n, n)))
```

here is the comparison for 100 to 100M items (slower runtime is the best):

[image: numpy vs pandas dataframe sort]

Same graph with the speed relative to pandas

[image: numpy vs pandas dataframe sort]

Answer (score 0):

By still using `df.sort_values()` you can speed it up a bit by selecting the type of sorting algorithm. By default it's set to quicksort, but there is the alternatives of 'mergesort', 'heapsort' and 'stable'.

Maybe specifying one of these would improve it?

```
df.sort_values(df.columns.to_list(), kind="mergesort")
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: Thanks for answering! For clarity, can you please format your code as code? Cheers!